# Bypass Clipboard History in the Windows 10 October 2018 Update

Tags: c++, winapi

We have a C++ app the makes heavy use of the clipboard API `OpenClipboard` etc.

The app is frequently saving the contents of the clipboard, inserting content, pasting and then restoring the clipboard.

With the Windows 10 October update this is causing a lot of Clipboard History that may also be synced between devices.

Is there a new `api` to bypass the new clipboard history?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally found a way to do this - supported by microsoft and finally documented here: [Cloud Clipboard and Clipboard History Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-formats#cloud-clipboard-and-clipboard-history-formats)

You need to get a couple of format ids first

```
UINT clipboardHistoryFormat_ = RegisterClipboardFormat(L"CanIncludeInClipboardHistory");
UINT cloudClipboardFormat_ = RegisterClipboardFormat(L"CanUploadToCloudClipboard");
```

Then when you write anything to the clipboard that you don't want in the Windows 10 History or Cloud you then need to also set the above formats with a `DWORD` value of 0

```
auto number_of_bytes = sizeof(DWORD);
auto hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE | GMEM_ZEROINIT, number_of_bytes);
if (hMem != nullptr)
{
    if (SetClipboardData(clipboardHistoryFormat_, hMem) == nullptr)
    {
        // something went wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good to know. For the sake of completeness, per the linked docs: `L"ExcludeClipboardContentFromMonitorProcessing"` - with any value - can be used to prevent inclusion in the local history _as well as_ preventing syncing the data being placed on the clipboard _to the cloud_.